# Did Android re-draw all the screen when only one small view changed?

Tags: android

I just did an experiment, a big `ImageView` in full-screen size and a small `ImageView` in the center. I changed the src of small `ImageView` and only small `ImageView`'s `onDraw` is called.

I was wondering if the big `ImageView`'s `onDraw` wasn't called, why can I see it on screen?

I guess the GPU rendering is based on the last snapshot of the GPU buffer and only submits the change in every `VSYNC`. So if there's no change in this area, it will show the content as the last frame.

Am I wrong? Please give me your idea about this.

Comment: It may help to watch: [Drawn out: How Android renders (Google I/O '18)](https://youtu.be/zdQRIYOST64)

Answer (score 0):

Only the views that change need to be redrawn.  Why would the rest need to be?

What happens when you change the image in an imageView is that it calls invalidate() on that view. This marks the view as dirty and needing a redraw.  This will cause its onDraw to be called on the next render pass.  Views that aren't invalid don't change, thus don't need their onDraw called.

Comment: Agree! But another question is that, if only this view is redrawn, why we can see the whole screen in the next frame? I mean if the other view is not redrawn, the area of them should be black, right?

Comment: @LeonWick Because the views that aren't redrawn just have the same data.  Imagine that the screen is a 2d matrix in memory, 3 bytes per pixel (which it more or less is).  Only the bytes for the view that gets redrawn need to change.  The rest don't get turned to black, they just stay the same.  So that's what happens-  the view draws to the area of the screen it's laid out at, and the rest stays the same as the last frame.

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks for your explanation! I was wondering is there any official document that describes this kind of process?

Comment: Not that I know of, but this is all kind of standard.  Every OS I've ever worked on that does video output worked more or less the same way-  some even more detailed (invalid areas could be sub-views and not redraw the whole view).

Comment: Got it, thanks very much!